# Zend Framework and a "Virtual Host" on IIS

Tags: zend-framework, iis, iis-7

I was able to get PHP setup correctly using the Web Platform installer. I have never touched IIS in my life, so this is an extremely simple question. My public web folder is here:

```
c:\inetpub\wwwroot\example\public
```

Although I just testing it out locally, I obviously would like to only expose the public folder. I know how to do this with Apache & my virtual host. Currently I load the site like this:

```
http://localhost/example/public
```

But would like to do it like this:

```
http://localhost
```

I am guessing I need to change paths, etc. but on top of it throwing a 404  when I change the physical path within IIS, I also want to make sure I don't miss anything. Which I am, because when I change the physical path on the website in IIS, it can't find anything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you look at this:
[How to: Create and Configure Virtual Directories in IIS 7.0](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb763173.aspx)

Comment: I am sure the solution is in there somewhere, but I didn't have time to go digging for it. I just found someone on our IT support team to help me. If I knew what he did I would post it here. :)